# How to correctly move objects at different speeds in the direction of the `Y` axis

Tags: javascript

Tried to make a script like this:

```
let intervals = [],
isClick = [],
isGameOver = false,
countElement = 3,
count = 0,
gameOver = function () {
  if (isGameOver) {
     return;
  }
  isGameOver = true;
  if (countElement <= count) {
     for (var i = 0; i < intervals.legth; ++i) {
        clearInterval(intervals[i]);
     }
     intervals = [];
     countElement = 0;
  }
},
elm = function (index) {
   return function () {
     if (isGameOver || isClick[index]) {
         return null;
     }
     isClick[index] = true;
     clearInterval(intervals[index]);
     intervals[index] = null;
     if (!intervals.filter(a => a).length) {
        count = countElement;
        gameOver();
        return;
     }
   };
};
for (let i = 0; i < 17; ++i) {
    setTimeout(() => {
       element.on('pointerup', elm(i));
       intervals[i] = setInterval(() => {
          if (countElement <= count) {
              clearInterval(intervals[i]);
              gameOver();
              return;
          }
          if (-64 > element.position.y) {
              clearInterval(intervals[i]);
              intervals[i] = null;
              ++count;
          } else {
              element.position.y -= 30;
          }
      }, pos.speed);
    }, pos.startTime * i);
}
```

It actually works, but for some reason it doesn't always work as it should.

Perhaps I'll tell you right away what is required ..
It is necessary to generate the required number of elements and move along the axis `Y`.

They must have different speeds.
I tried to solve it like this:

```
let rnd = function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}, pos = {
    speed: Math.floor(rnd(100, rnd(370, 470))),
    startTime: Math.floor(rnd(rnd(370, 470), rnd(700, 1000)))
}
```

In general, I would like to see the elements start flying with different departure and flight speeds, there were attempts that can be missed if the element flew away, when you click on the element, it stops.

Well, in fact, if all the elements flew out - it doesn't matter if they flew away or stopped, the main thing is that all intervals should stop and there would be a kind of exit ...

Connoisseurs help out how this can be done without third-party libraries?

How to do it correctly, please show.

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing the problem in a "working" example. Can you post a demonstrator of your problem code using the <> (Javascript/HTML/Css snippet Cntrl-M) button on the stackoverflow editor toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved...
There was no need to zero out `countElement` and `intervals` in `gameOver`.
Because of this, subsequent intervals were looped, as the indices were violated.